# How can I save my own html boilerplate for future use shortcut?

Tags: html, shortcut, html5boilerplate

I know we have this '!' shortcut so as to automatically fill in a standard html boilerplate.

But I want to add one line to it() and save this form for future use - how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
open your vs code

1. go to view->command palette or (ctr + shift + P)
2. type and enter Snippets:Configure User Snippets
3. select and enter ' html.json '
4. copy and paste below code

   "boilerplatecode": {

   ```
           "prefix": "boilerplatecode",

           "body": [
           "<html>",

   "<head>",

   "</head>",
   "<body>",

   "</body>",
   "</html>"

           ],

           "description": "Log output to console"
       }
   }
   ```
5. Edit code inside the squre bracket and save it
6. create a html page and type shortcut key boilerplatecode and enter then the code automatically come in your editor.

Comment: thanks, I tried that, but perhaps somewhere on the way did some error, I don't know, but it didn't work. I should enter "boilerplatecode" the word right inside of index.html in the first line like we type "!" to get a regular palatte, right?